# How to reduce size of ipa from xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I am working a kids app. It has number of video files and png files. All to gather came to size of 1.6GB after compressing. Is there any way to reduce the file size to use in app.

Comment: What file format/resolution are the video files? What resolution are the PNGs? Does all content have to be self-contained or can you assume data connection to download, or option for in-app purchase (even if free) to download data at a later time from a server?

Comment: Download the video and png files opening app

Answer (score 2):

1. try compress your image resources.
   [imageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) is good choice.
2. some kind of unnecessary resources, you can make it to download. Video always the hard-disk space killer, put it in the server, if you want to display it, request it and download it as cache.

Comment: **imageOptim** is good, but now I hv to check it weather is really effectible or not...